# Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: an object error

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete a post, but I keep getting the error. It means that I have to convert the id from object to string right? I have tried to convert it to string by using toString(), but it doesn't work.

```
const deletePosts = (userId, postId) => {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("posts")
            .doc(userId)
            .collection("userPosts")
            .doc(postId)
            .delete()
}
```

When I console.log the id, it shows. Below the code in the same file, I use Flatlist, so that's why it's (item.id).

```
<TouchableOpacity
       title="Delete"
       onPress={() => deletePosts(item.id)} >
       <Text>Delete</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I think the document id you are passing is an empty string.

Comment: Then how can I solve it?

Comment: You have to pass the doc id if you want to update or delete a document

Comment: Looks like you are only passing the first variable (userId as item.id), but not the second (postId). And could you also provide which error are you getting?